# Problem with in-place operation during backward operation

Tags: python, math, pytorch

I'm working on a code and i have this function :

```
def tracejacob(jacob):
    a11,a22=jacob[0,0,:,:],jacob[1,1,:,:]
    return a11+a22
```

and this one

```
def fwd_inf_2d(m,K,phi,phiinv,timesteps): #m0 initial momenta, K is the kernel, deltat is the time step, timesteps is the number of time steps
    n,h,w=m.shape
    deltat=1/timesteps
    idty=get_idty_2d(h,w)

    for t in range(timesteps):
        v=K(m)
        phi = phi + compose_function_2d(v,phi)*deltat
        phiinv = compose_function_2d(phiinv,idty-v*deltat)
        jacob_v=get_jacobian_matrix_2d(v)
        jacob_m=get_jacobian_matrix_2d(m)
        DvTm = jacobxvectorfield(jacob_v,m,transpose_jacob=True)
        Dmv= jacobxvectorfield(jacob_m,v,transpose_jacob=False)
        divvm = tracejacob(jacob_v)*m
        
        m = m - DvTm - Dmv - divvm
    return(phi,phiinv)
```

Then i try to compute loss.backward() where only m has a gradient. So the backward is computed only for m. But i have the error `RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [2, 50, 50]] is at version 1; expected version 0 instead` and it says that the error is related with the line `divvm = tracejacob(jacob_v)*m`

Why is this an in-place operation and how can i turn it into a normal one please ?

Comment: That's where the problem was detected, not where the in-place operation occurred.

Comment: @user2357112 are you sure ? Because I used torch.autogras.set_detect_anomaly(True) to see where the in-place operation occured. Maybe I misunderstand this command